# Highcharts: Preventing Users from unchecking all Legends in the chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How can I make sure that the last checked legend does not get unchecked?

Comment: Which chart are you using?

Comment: Im sorry, didnt state that.

Comment: Here is what im curently working on. Thanks [link](http://jsfiddle.net/amberg007/j6n3t2bd/)

Answer (score 0):

You can catch [legendItemClick](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick) and prepare function which will check visible/invisible series and run action or not.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thanks for the rely. im relatively new to JavaScript and jQuery in general. A simple code sample would be appreciated. tnx